# Which way is this coordination equilibrium likely to lie (entropic vs enthalpic factors)?

Tags: coordination-compounds

The question is asking where this aqueous equilibrium is likely to lie.

My thought process is that, because Li+ is a smaller cation than Na+, with a greater charge density, upon displacement it will order solvent (water) molecules around itself more than Na+. This would result in the forward reaction likely having a positive entropy change, making it unfavourable. This means that the equilibrium would likely lie to the left.

On the other hand, I can see the argument being made that Li+ is so small that it is unlikely to coordinate well to the O and N lone pairs, meaning the M-L bonds on the left hand side of the equilibrium equation will likely be weak and easily broken in favour of stronger Na-O and Na-N bonds. This would mean that the equilibrium would likely lie to the right.

I have a suspicion that the entropic considerations outlined in the first paragraph are more important in determining the direction of equilibrium (and outweigh the enthalpies factors in paragraph 2) but just wanted to confirm if this is the case?

[image: The equilibrium]

[image: The macrocycle]

Comment: There's no need for some lengthy analysis - Li is simply too small to fit well - that's like the main point of crown ethers and cryptands - they are size selective.

Comment: @Mithoron ok got it thank you very much. Would entropic considerations be of any significance here though, or is this purely driven by enthalpy (strength of M-L bond)?